# NODE.JS Execute Code in specific order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code that parses a pcap file and writes the parsed data into an array `data = []` and then writes that data to a JSON file:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var pcapp = require('pcap-parser');
var hex = "";
var data = [];
var i = 0;

function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
        return str;
}

var parser = pcapp.parse('C:/Users/Brandt Winkler Prins/Desktop/data.pcap');
parser.on('packet', function(packet) {
    hex = [...packet.data].map(_ => ('0' +_.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join();
    var ticker = hex2a(hex.substring(282, 306).replace(/,/g,""));
    var bidPrice = parseInt(hex.substring(318,342).split(",").reverse().join(""), 16);
    var timestamp = parseInt(hex.substring(258, 282).split(",").reverse().join(""), 16);
    if(packet.header.capturedLength == 126 && ticker == "AAPL    ") {
       data[2*i] = bidPrice;
       data[2*i-1] = timestamp;
       i++
    }
 });
 data = JSON.stringify(data);
fs.writeFile("C:/Users/Brandt Winkler Prins/Desktop/Project/data.json",data);
```

All of the data gets written to its respective array in `parser.on(...)` however node.js executes my `.writeFile` command before it executes `parser.on(...)`. In sum, my question is this: how can I force node to execute my code before writing my file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write to file after finishing parsing

```
parser.on('end', function(){
  data = JSON.stringify(data);
  fs.writeFile("C:/Users/Brandt Winkler Prins/Desktop/Project/data.json",data);
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks and get that commentator badge

Answer (score 1):

Your parser will read one packet at a time from the file, and raise the `on()` method for each packet.

How do you know that the quantity of packets have been reached before writing to your file?

You could do:

1. Make a simple methode, like `check_finished_and_save()` which you add at the end of your `on()` and which controls that there is no more data to read. If yes, it writes to file.
2. You could simply append your results to your file (mode `a` for `append`). Each time `on()` is called you append the results at the end of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Capture end event for your parser and do your stuff like stringify and write file operations

```
parser.on('end', function (session) {
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFile("C:/Users/Brandt Winkler Prins/Desktop/Project/data.json",data);
});
```